Is there any way to modify the request headers which is sent by web browser download manager?
When the user download a file from http server, I want to insert some user info into the http headers by javascript, but I also want the download can be paused and resumed by the download manager, if I use a  to transfer the download process to the download manager of the web browser, I lose the chance to insert headers into the http request it sends. So how to solve it?
